# Laser Scanner Data Fluctuation

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using 2 laser scanners, that are produced on two topics scan1 and scan2 respectively. After remapping both topics to one topic scan, the data are fluctuating, it goes in a cycle sometimes it reads from scan1 and sometimes from scan2 although the topic is scan now. Any help please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238709/laser-scanner-data-fluctuation/) by [wassimhariri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26309/wassimhariri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it fluctuates because whenever a new scan message arrives it will be shown up and the old one will be discarded. And your data will be arriving alternately from each laser. You could use the [laser assebmler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) to combine both scans.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0